# SMS reponse is not working properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms

When test a SMS response without any AMPscript, it is working fine.
But when I place the below AMPscript, it is neither showing error response nor showing positive response.

Below is the AMPscript:

It is a simple AMPscript which just adds a record in data extension.
Please help!

```
%%[

var @Department_internal_name__c
set @Department_internal_name__c = "Book"
set @mobileNumber= MOBILE_NUMBER
Set @SubscriberKeyRow = LookupRows('Test SMS Response','MobilePhone',@mobileNumber)
If ROWCOUNT(@SubscriberKeyRow) > 0 THEN
Set @Row5 = Row(@SubscriberKeyRow,1)
SET @email = Field(@Row5,'Email')
SET @Contact__c = Field(@Row5,'Contact__c')
ENDIF
set @upsertCount = upsertData("Test SMS Response",1,"Contact__c",@Contact__c,"Email",@email,"Department_internal_name__c",@Department_internal_name__c,"MobilePhone",@mobileNumber)

]%%
```

Comment: I would suggest troubleshooting your ampscript within a cloud page or email studio, where you code a value for @mobilenumber. My initial guess if you lookup function is not retrieving a row does the col mobilephone have the phone number in the correct format no dashes or spaces or +

Comment: Hey @razor, is there any other text/values in the SMS message? The code you shared above has no output/text.